# CNN approaches to detection which are not bounding box based

Tags: image-processing, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

Most of the approaches to detection problems are based more or less on some form of bounding box proposal, which turns to two class (positive/negative) classification. I found lots of materials on these topics.

But I was wondering, aren't there some approaches taking the whole image as an input, then sending it through several convolutional and pooling layers, output of which would be two numbers (`x, y` position of the object)? Of course this would mean that there's just one object in the image. So far I haven't find anything about this, should I consider it not usable?

Comment: Most object detection solutions consider the detection problem as providing location + **size**, and hence x, y aren't enough - you get the location but not the size. According to your question, it looks like you're referring to RPN, AKA 2 stage, detection approach (such as faster-RCNN). However there are methods that work differently such as YOLO and SSD. Another interesting approach that works in a different way - is the following: http://www.di.ens.fr/~josef/publications/Oquab15.pdf. Worth reading.

Comment: there is an alternative approach called semantic segmentation, although different from what you mention, this approach outputs an image which says whether a pixel contains that object or not.